# I cannot add my products to cart when I clicked button in react.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, router

I am doing a e commerce website with fakestoreapi I added products and it can be filterable by category. But when I click add to cart it doesnt work. Please help me

Comment: Can yo provide code sample?

Comment: Hey ESRA! Welcome to stackoverflow!
When asking a question its important to include a Minimal, Reproducible Example.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.